# How do I disable a Button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, button

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set the enabled state of a button in Flutter.

From the docs, it says to set `onPressed` to null to disable a button, and give it a value to enable it. This is fine if the button continues to be in the same state for the lifecycle.

I get the impression I need to create a custom Stateful widget that will allow me to update the button's enabled state (or onPressed callback) somehow.

How would I do that? This seems like a pretty straightforward requirement, but I can't find anything in the docs on how to do it.

Answer (score 267, accepted):

I think you may want to introduce some helper functions to `build` your button as well as a Stateful widget along with some property to key off of.

- Use a StatefulWidget/State and create a variable to hold your condition (e.g. `isButtonDisabled`)
- Set this to true initially (if that's what you desire)
- When rendering the button, **don't directly set the `onPressed`** value to either `null` or some function `onPressed: () {}`
- **Instead**, conditionally set it using a ternary or a helper function *(example below)*
- Check the `isButtonDisabled` as part of this conditional and return either `null` or some function.
- When the button is pressed (or whenever you want to disable the button) use `setState(() => isButtonDisabled = true)` to flip the conditional variable.
- Flutter will call the `build()` method again with the new state and the button will be rendered with a `null` press handler and be disabled.

Here's is some more context using the Flutter counter project.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  bool _isButtonDisabled;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _isButtonDisabled = false;
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _isButtonDisabled = true;
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("The App"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            new Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
            _buildCounterButton(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCounterButton() {
    return new RaisedButton(
      child: new Text(
        _isButtonDisabled ? "Hold on..." : "Increment"
      ),
      onPressed: _isButtonDisabled ? null : _incrementCounter,
    );
  }
}
```

In this example I am using an inline ternary to conditionally set the `Text` and `onPressed`, but it may be more appropriate for you to extract this into a function (you can use this same method to change the text of the button as well):

```
Widget _buildCounterButton() {
    return new RaisedButton(
      child: new Text(
        _isButtonDisabled ? "Hold on..." : "Increment"
      ),
      onPressed: _counterButtonPress(),
    );
  }

  Function _counterButtonPress() {
    if (_isButtonDisabled) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return () {
        // do anything else you may want to here
        _incrementCounter();
      };
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to add fat arrow function as an argument, otherwise the _incrementCounter() function will be called right away when button becomes enabled. This way it will actually wait until the button is clicked:

The onPressed should look like this:
`onPressed: _isButtonDisabled ? null :  () => _incrementCounter`

Comment: @vitVeres that is usually true but the _counterButtonPress() is returning a function `return () {}` so this is intentional. I don't want to use the fat arrow here as I want the function to execute and return `null` and disable the button.

Comment: @AshtonThomas Yeah, in the extracted method _counterButtonPress() it is exactly as you explained, but I was referencing to the code with ternary operator before you suggested the extraction. In your first example it will cause the execution of _incrementCounter() method when button should be enabled. Next time I'll try to point out what I mean more precisely :)

Comment: What was wrong with using a ```disabled``` property, Flutter team? This is just not intuitive :-/

Comment: the correct way is with AbsorbPointer or IgnorePointer. Simply widget way instead of logic with setting up onPressed to null.

Comment: This is not good enough because it assumes the onPress: is synchronous code while it is very possible the code is asynchronous and operational, splitting every button code to multiple function to work around this causes a maintenance nightmare

Answer (score 341):

According to the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons):

> If the `onPressed` callback is null, then the button will be disabled
> and by default will resemble a flat button in the `disabledColor`.

So, you might do something like this:

```dart
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: calculateWhetherDisabledReturnsBool() ? null : () => whatToDoOnPressed,
  child: Text('Button text')
);
```

Comment: Judging from the docs, this is how it's ment to be implemented.
With the accepted answer properties like `disabledElevation`, `disabledColor` and `DisabledTextColor` won't work as intended.

Comment: Pff thanks for this Steve, was not planning on going through all the code of the currently accepted answer. @chris84948, consider changing this to the accepted answer.

Comment: yes, but can you destroy the house from inside and still run away? or can you null the onPress from setStatus within the onPress?

Comment: Although, after  null safety  we can not use 'null' so you can use                     `onPressed: _isLoading ? () => {} : () => _signImWithGoogle(context),`

Comment: Here in 2023, [ElevatedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html) is the new widget. Use this docs link since the one in the answer 404s.

"If onPressed and onLongPress callbacks are null, then the button will be disabled."

Answer (score 115):

The simple answer is `onPressed : null` gives a disabled button.

Answer (score 72):

**Disables click:**

```
onPressed: null
```

**Enables click:**

```
onPressed: () => fooFunction() 
// or
onPressed: fooFunction
```

**Combination:**

```dart
onPressed: shouldEnable ? fooFunction : null
```

Answer (score 33):

For a specific and limited number of widgets, wrapping them in a widget [IgnorePointer](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) does exactly this: when its `ignoring` property is set to true, the sub-widget (actually, the entire subtree) is not clickable.

```
IgnorePointer(
    ignoring: true, // or false
    child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _logInWithFacebook,
        child: Text("Facebook sign-in"),
        ),
),
```

Otherwise, if you intend to disable an entire subtree, look into AbsorbPointer().

Comment: how do you handle code crush or error in code execution to release the ignoring ?

Comment: This is a much better option in my opinion. All of the others visually show the button as pressable, they just don't do anything. This is the only suggestion that visually indicates unpressable.

Answer (score 22):

This is the easiest way in my opinion:

```
RaisedButton(
  child: Text("PRESS BUTTON"),
  onPressed: booleanCondition
    ? () => myTapCallback()
    : null
)
```

Answer (score 17):

Enable and Disable functionality is same for most of the widgets.

Ex, button , switch, checkbox etc.

Just set the `onPressed` property as shown below

`onPressed : null` returns **Disabled widget**

`onPressed : (){}` or `onPressed : _functionName` returns **Enabled widget**

Answer (score 16):

You can also use the AbsorbPointer, and you can use it in the following way:

```
AbsorbPointer(
      absorbing: true, // by default is true
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: (){
          print('pending to implement onPressed function');
        },
        child: Text("Button Click!!!"),
      ),
    ),
```

If you want to know more about this widget, you can check the following link [Flutter Docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html)

Comment: Ignore-/AbsorbPointer does not consider the disabled styles just as a REMINDER :-)

Answer (score 16):

This answer is based on updated Buttons `TextButton/ElevatedButton/OutlinedButton` for `Flutter 2.x`

Still, buttons are enabled or disabled based on `onPressed` property. If that property is null then button would be disabled. If you will assign function to `onPressed` then button would be enabled.
In the below snippets, I have shown how to enable/disable button and update it's style accordingly.

> This post also indicating that how to apply different styles to new
> Flutter 2.x buttons.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool textBtnswitchState = true;
  bool elevatedBtnSwitchState = true;
  bool outlinedBtnState = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  child: Text('Text Button'),
                  onPressed: textBtnswitchState ? () {} : null,
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                      (states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                          return Colors.grey;
                        } else {
                          return Colors.red;
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text('Change State'),
                    Switch(
                      value: textBtnswitchState,
                      onChanged: (newState) {
                        setState(() {
                          textBtnswitchState = !textBtnswitchState;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            Divider(),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Text Button'),
                  onPressed: elevatedBtnSwitchState ? () {} : null,
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                      (states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                          return Colors.grey;
                        } else {
                          return Colors.white;
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text('Change State'),
                    Switch(
                      value: elevatedBtnSwitchState,
                      onChanged: (newState) {
                        setState(() {
                          elevatedBtnSwitchState = !elevatedBtnSwitchState;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            Divider(),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                OutlinedButton(
                  child: Text('Outlined Button'),
                  onPressed: outlinedBtnState ? () {} : null,
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                    (states) {
                      if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                        return Colors.grey;
                      } else {
                        return Colors.red;
                      }
                    },
                  ), side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                    if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                      return BorderSide(color: Colors.grey);
                    } else {
                      return BorderSide(color: Colors.red);
                    }
                  })),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text('Change State'),
                    Switch(
                      value: outlinedBtnState,
                      onChanged: (newState) {
                        setState(() {
                          outlinedBtnState = !outlinedBtnState;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For disabling any **Button** in flutter such as `FlatButton`, `RaisedButton`, `MaterialButton`, `IconButton` etc all you need to do is to set the `onPressed` and `onLongPress` properties to **null**. Below is some simple examples for some of the buttons:

**FlatButton (Enabled)**

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: (){}, 
  onLongPress: null, // Set one as NOT null is enough to enable the button
  textColor: Colors.black,
  disabledColor: Colors.orange,
  disabledTextColor: Colors.white,
  child: Text('Flat Button'),
),
```

[image]  [image]

**FlatButton (Disabled)**

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: null,
  onLongPress: null,
  textColor: Colors.black,
  disabledColor: Colors.orange,
  disabledTextColor: Colors.white,
  child: Text('Flat Button'),
),
```

[image]

**RaisedButton (Enabled)**

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: (){},
  onLongPress: null, // Set one as NOT null is enough to enable the button
  // For when the button is enabled
  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
  textColor: Colors.black,
  splashColor: Colors.blue,
  elevation: 8.0,

  // For when the button is disabled
  disabledTextColor: Colors.white,
  disabledColor: Colors.orange,
  disabledElevation: 0.0,

  child: Text('Raised Button'),
),
```

[image]

**RaisedButton (Disabled)**

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: null,
  onLongPress: null,
  // For when the button is enabled
  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
  textColor: Colors.black,
  splashColor: Colors.blue,
  elevation: 8.0,

  // For when the button is disabled
  disabledTextColor: Colors.white,
  disabledColor: Colors.orange,
  disabledElevation: 0.0,

  child: Text('Raised Button'),
),
```

[image]

**IconButton (Enabled)**

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  icon: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard_rounded),
  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            
  disabledColor: Colors.orange,
),
```

[image]  [image]

**IconButton (Disabled)**

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: null,
  icon: Icon(Icons.card_giftcard_rounded),
  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            
  disabledColor: Colors.orange,
),
```

[image]

**Note**: Some of buttons such as `IconButton` have only the `onPressed` property.

Answer (score 8):

This is the easiest way to disable a button in Flutter is assign the `null` value to the `onPressed`

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.blue, // background
    onPrimary: Colors.white, // foreground
  ),
  onPressed: null,
  child: Text('ElevatedButton'),
),
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways of doing this:

1- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49354576/5499531

2- You can use a MaterialStatesController:

```
final _statesController = MaterialStatesController();
```

and then change the state to:

```
_statesController.update(
   MaterialState.disabled,
   true, // or false depending on your logic
);
```

On your button

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: _onPressed,
    statesController: _statesController,
    child: Text("Awesome"),
),
```

In addition you can change the button style when is disable:
in your theme setup:

```
....
elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: colors.primary500, // set your own color
                textStyle: button, // set your own style
                onPrimary: colors.onPrimary100, // set your own color
                enableFeedback: true,
                disabledBackgroundColor: colors.primary300, // set your own color
                disabledForegroundColor: colors.primary300, // set your own color
                disabledMouseCursor: SystemMouseCursors.forbidden, // when is disable the change the cursor type
              ),
            ),
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code in your app for button with loading and disable:

```
class BtnPrimary extends StatelessWidget {
  bool loading;
  String label;
  VoidCallback onPressed;

  BtnPrimary(
      {required this.label, required this.onPressed, this.loading = false});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton.icon(
      icon: loading
          ? const SizedBox(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              width: 20,
              height: 20)
          : const SizedBox(width: 0, height: 0),
      label: loading ? const Text('Waiting...'): Text(label),
      onPressed: loading ? null : onPressed,
    );
  }
}
```

I hope useful

Answer (score 0):

You can set also blank condition, in place of set null

```
         var isDisable=true;

   

          RaisedButton(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.green,
              onPressed:  isDisable
                  ? () => (){} : myClickingData(),
              child: Text('Button'),
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

see below of the possible solution, add a  'ValueListenableBuilder' of 'TextEditingValue'  listening to controller (TextEditingController) and return your function call  if controller.text is not empty and return 'null' if it is empty.

// valuelistenablebuilder wraped around button

```
  ValueListenableBuilder<TextEditingValue>(
                  valueListenable: textFieldController,
                  builder: (context, ctrl, __) => ElevatedButton(                    
                    onPressed: ctrl.text.isNotEmpty ? yourFunctionCall : null,
                    child: Text(
                      'SUBMIT',
                      style: GoogleFonts.roboto(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

//texfield

```
 TextField(controller: textFieldController,
                 onChanged: (newValue) {
                  textFieldText = newValue;
                },
              ),
```

builder will  listen to controller and enables button only when textfield is in use. I hope this answers the question. let me know..

Answer (score -2):

I like to use flutter_mobx for this and work on the state.

Next I use an observer:

```
Container(child: Observer(builder: (_) {
  var method;
  if (!controller.isDisabledButton) method = controller.methodController;
  return RaiseButton(child: Text('Test') onPressed: method);
}));
```

On the Controller:

```
@observable
bool isDisabledButton = true;
```

Then inside the control you can manipulate this variable as you want.

Refs.: [Flutter mobx](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mobx)

Answer (score -6):

If you are searching for a quick way and don't care about letting the user actually clicking more then once on a button. You could do it also the following way:

```
// Constant whether button is clicked
bool isClicked = false;
```

and then checking in the onPressed() function whether the user has already clicked the button or not.

```
onPressed: () async {
    if (!isClicked) {
       isClicked = true;
       // await Your normal function
    } else {
       Toast.show(
          "You click already on this button", context,
          duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
    }
}
```