# In flutter, RaisedButton has disabledColor option in its constructor but no option to disable it?

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter, `Raisedbutton` has `disabledColor` option in its constructor but not any option to disable it? So how can someone apply the `disabledColor` when there is no information about whether `RaisedButton` is disabled or not.

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49354576/3266152) answers your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable a Button in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351648/how-do-i-disable-a-button-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

If don't set  `onPressed` callback, the button will be disabled.

```
RaisedButton(
  child:Text("Disabled)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `onPressed` otherwise IDE will show error/warning. 
Use this,

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: null, // disables the button
  disabledColor: Colors.orange,
  child: Text("Disabled"),
)
```

**Output:**

[image]