# What is the correct way of disabling the button when it contains empty string or spaces

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form for user information and if one of the fields are empty I want to disable the submit button but my `setState` is not updating the flags.
Here is my `validateFields` function which is being called inside a `build` method. **Regex is 100% correct (I checked it multiple times)**

```
void validateFields() {
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r'[!@#<>?"\s:_`~;[\]\\|=+)(*&^%-]|^$');
    if (regExp.hasMatch(nameController.text) || regExp.hasMatch(surnameController.text) || regExp.hasMatch(phoneController.text)){
      setState(() {
        isButtonDisabled = true;
      });
    }
    else {
      setState(() {
        isButtonDisabled = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

And Here is my submit button

```
onPressed: isButtonDisabled ? null : (){
 //upload the form
}
```

Comment: when are you calling the function validateFields?

Comment: @AnirudhBagri I am calling it inside the build method before the return statement

Comment: I think isButtonDisabled = true; this should be in else block and vice versa

Comment: @jutsm555 No it should not

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49354576/10150796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by adding the listener to the textController

```
nameController.addListener(() { 
     validateField(nameController.text);
    });
```

```
  void validateField(text) {
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r'[!@#<>?"\s:_`~;[\]\\|=+)(*&^%-]|^$');
   if (regExp.hasMatch(text)) {
       setState(() {
         isButtonDisabled = true;
       });
     } else {
       setState(() {
         isButtonDisabled = false;
       });
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` method rebuilds the widget tree, so all your widgets will get refreshed.

One way is to consider checking for regex validation after the button is clicked.
Simply show a snackbar warning if regex doesnt match or do the next action if it matches.

Second would be to change the state of button when some text is submitted in the text field. You can use `TextController` to change the state of the button whenever something is written.