# how to make a button disable in flutter

Tags: flutter, button, disable

I'am trying to create a profile form . I want to disable or enable the button based on the validation. I tried to check  the currentstate of form validated or not. it is working fine but when i type on one of  the textFormField , I am getting error message on all of the textFormField .
Here is the code i'am working.

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';




class ProfileForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProfileForm> createState() => _ProfileFormState();
}

class _ProfileFormState extends State<ProfileForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  final _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _dobController = TextEditingController();
  final _currentLocationController = TextEditingController();
  final _locationIndiaController = TextEditingController();
  bool btndisable = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    RegExp emailValidator = RegExp(
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$');

    return Scaffold(

      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(

          key: _formKey,
          onChanged: () {
            notdisbled();
           
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Let’s create a profile for you",
                style: AppTextStyleSecondary.headline2sec,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 100.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Please enter your personal details",
                  
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              Text("Your name"),
              TextFormField(
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                onChanged: (val) {
                 
                },
                validator: (val) {
                  if (val.toString().length < 2) {
                    return "Please enter your name";
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                controller: _nameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    isDense: true,
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 12)),
              ),

              Text(labelText: "Date of Birth"),
              InkWell(
                child: TextFormField(

                  onTap: () {
                    _selectDate(context);
                  },
                  validator: (val) {
                    if (val.toString().isEmpty) {
                      return "This field is required";
                    } else {
                      return null;
                    }
                  },
                  readOnly: true,
                  controller: _dobController,
          
                ),
              ),
          
              Text("Email address"),
              TextFormField(
    
                controller: _emailController,
                onChanged: (val) {},
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                validator: (val) {
                  String email = val!.trim();
                  if (emailValidator.hasMatch(email)) {
                    return null;
                  } else {
                    return "Enter valid email address";
                  }
                },
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    isDense: true,
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 12)),
              ),

              Text(labelText: "Your location where you currently live"),
              TextFormField(
               autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                validator: (val) {
                  if (val.toString().isEmpty) {
                    return "This field is required";
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                onChanged: (val) {
         
                },

                controller: _currentLocationController,
            
              ),
              Text("Your location in India"),
              TextFormField(
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                validator: (val) {
                  if (val.toString().isEmpty) {
                    return "This field is required";
                  } else {
   

                    return null;
                  }
                },
                onChanged: (val) {},

                controller: _locationIndiaController,
                
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 25,
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 45,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: btndisable ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                              'HomeScreen', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                    }
                  }
                  child: Text("Continue"),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1970),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
        _dobController.text =
            "${selectedDate.day}/${selectedDate.month}/${selectedDate.year}";
      });
    }
  }

  void notdisbled() {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate() == false) {
      setState(() {
        btndisable = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        btndisable = true;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if its disable you need to give null property to the button like this 
onPressed: isDisabled ? null : (){buttonclickevent}

Comment: try removing autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction on every TextFormField

Comment: @SabahatHussainQureshi I tied that but still getting the same error

Comment: Can you include full [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)widget

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable a Button in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351648/how-do-i-disable-a-button-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

for disable the button change to this :

```
child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: _formKey.currentState != null && _formKey.currentState.validate() ? () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          'HomeScreen', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                  }: null,
                  child: AppText(
                      text: "Continue",
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: AppColor.white),
                ),
```

but when you use

> formKey.currentState!.validate()

when you type any thing, flutter try call it every time so your form widget run all validator func in all its textfield. so it is natural for all textfield to get error message

Comment: getting null check error

Comment: I think it will be always disable state, because  it will get null and never will active state

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: @eamirho3ein still having the same error

Comment: the null issue is in your validator funcs, you should correct them all. for example the first textfield should be like this : validator: (val) {
                  if (val != null && val.toString().length < 2) {
                    return "Please enter your name";
                  }
                  return null;
                },