# ElevatedButton disable onPressed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-onpressed

There are 4 ElevatedButtons in my widget in a Row. If one of them is pressed an image will be shown based on the button. This image comes from an API so it takes a bit to load.
Is it possible to disable the not-selected buttons while the data from the API arrives?

This is the code of the button:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 3),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        primary: mainBgColor,
      ),
      onPressed: showImage,
      child: Text(
        title,
      ),
    );
  }
```

And this is the function:

```
showImage: =>_controller.buttonTap(getImage(quizImages.wrong));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable a Button in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351648/how-do-i-disable-a-button-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take one variable which state changes respectively as below :

Start Api Calling :

```
isFetching = true
```

Api Success / Failure :

```
isFetching = false
```

Put below code at onPressed callback :

```
onPressed: isFetching ? null : showImage
```

Answer (score 1):

A button is disabled when the property `onPressed` is null. That is, you can assign null to your button `onPressed` or a callback based on a flag that is set while the image is fetched.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you need a variable that tells you if you're in loading state and then you can do:

```
onPressed: isLoading ? null : showImage
```