# how to disable button in Flutter 3.3.4

Tags: flutter, dart

in Flutter 3.3.4 , I want control the state of the button by passing an object with its properties
. I tried some solutions in stackoverflow (e.g [How do I disable a Button in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351648/how-do-i-disable-a-button-in-flutter) )，but failed。

I print the flag of the object , it looks right.

here is my code

```
// Copyright 2018 The Flutter team. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SwitchWidget wifiSwitch = SwitchWidget();
    // SwitchWidget timeSwitch = SwitchWidget();
    // SwitchWidget locationSwitch = SwitchWidget();

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Startup N1ame Generator',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Startup Name Generator'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Column(children: [wifiSwitch]),
              Column(children: [ButtonWidget(wifiSwitch)])
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SwitchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  bool flag = true;

  SwitchWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SwitchWidget> createState() => _SwitchWidgetState(this);
}

class _SwitchWidgetState extends State<SwitchWidget> {
  SwitchWidget switchWidget;

  _SwitchWidgetState(this.switchWidget);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Switch(
        value: switchWidget.flag,
        onChanged: (newValue) => {
          setState(() {
            switchWidget.flag = newValue;
            print("-----------${switchWidget.flag}");
          })
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ButtonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  late SwitchWidget _switchWidget;

  SwitchWidget get switchWidget => _switchWidget;

  set switchWidget(SwitchWidget switchWidget) => {
        print('The ButtonWidget is $switchWidget.'),
        _switchWidget = switchWidget
      };

  ButtonWidget(switchWidget, {Key? key}) : super(key: key) {
    this.switchWidget = switchWidget;
  }

  @override
  State<ButtonWidget> createState() => _ButtonWidgetState(switchWidget);
}

class _ButtonWidgetState extends State<ButtonWidget> {
  SwitchWidget switchWidget;

  _ButtonWidgetState(this.switchWidget);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 1, 1, 1),
      child: ElevatedButton(
          // color: Colors.blue,
          // disabledColor: Colors.grey,
          // textColor: Colors.black,
          child: Text("123"),
          // onPressed: () {},
          onPressed: this.switchWidget.flag ? _incrementCounter : null,
          style: ButtonStyle(
            foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
              (states) {
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                  return Colors.grey;
                } else {
                  return Colors.white;
                }
              },
            ),
          )),
    );
    {}
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    print("object******** ${this.switchWidget.flag}");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you pass a reference of SwitchWidget to _SwitchWidgetState? You should move the property `bool flag = true;` to _SwitchWidgetState and then change it directly in `setState(() => flag = newValue);`.

Also, your `ButtonWidget` is not rebuilt on change in `SwitchWidget`. You'll have to use some sort of state management in order to disable the button on a state change of your switch widget.

For example using callbacks:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ParentWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<ParentWidget> createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  bool _isDisabled = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SwitchWidget(initialValue: true, onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _isDisabled = val)),
        ButtonWidget(isDisabled: _isDisabled),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SwitchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool initialValue;
  final void Function(bool) onChanged;
  const SwitchWidget({super.key, required this.onChanged, required this.initialValue});

  @override
  State<SwitchWidget> createState() => _SwitchWidgetState();
}

class _SwitchWidgetState extends State<SwitchWidget> {
  late bool _value;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _value = widget.initialValue;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Switch(
      value: _value,
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() => _value = val);
        widget.onChanged(val);
      },
    );
  }
}

class ButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isDisabled;
  const ButtonWidget({super.key, required this.isDisabled});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: isDisabled
          ? null
          : () {
              //Some logic
            },
      child: Text("Press me!"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `null` where you place your function, or even some of Flutter's Widgets already have the `enabled` property. But `setState` and change the function to `null` and you should get what you want.